# rawmemchr: symbol not found in nodegit with docker

Tags: linux, node.js, docker, nodegit

When I run the server in the Docker container, everything works fine until I include the line `nodegit = require 'nodegit'`. If NodeGit is required, on `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error relocating
/usr/myContainer/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node:
 __rawmemchr: symbol not found
```

I tried NodeGit v.0.12.1 (the latest version) and v.0.11.0.

Without Docker, NodeGit works fine in the same project.

I am new to Docker and virtual machines generally. Any advice on how to troubleshoot this would really help. Thanks!

Update: here are the logs of my container:

```
[00:22:03] Requiring external module coffee-script/register
[00:22:04] Using gulpfile /usr/lada/gulpfile.coffee
[00:22:04] Starting 'lada-up'...
[00:22:04] Finished 'lada-up' after 23 ms
livereload[tiny-lr] listening on 35729 ...
Error: Error relocating /usr/lada/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node: __rawmemchr: symbol not found
  at Error (native)
  at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
  at Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lada/node_modules/nodegit/lib/nodegit.js:9:12)
  at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
  at Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lada/app/post.coffee:1:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lada/app/post.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
  at Object.loadFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
  at Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lada/app/index.coffee:8:6)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lada/app/index.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
  at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:134:23)
  at compileScript (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:224:29)
  at compilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:174:14)
  at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:98:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
  at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
  at startup (node.js:142:18)
  at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: have you installed : `npm install nodegit` in docker ,yet ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes, I have.

Comment: As I know : it's `nodegit = require ("nodegit");`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's CoffeeScript. All other dependencies that are required in this way work fine.

Comment: can you show me : `docker logs node_docker_id`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I've just added the output to the question. Thanks!